# PowerShell script to copy a file from a Mapped Network Drive to a Subfolder of the same mapped, network drive then add the date to the file name

Tags: powershell, copy, rename, paste

I'm new to PowerShell and have read many of the similar questions. The answers seem way to complicated for what I want to do. 
I want to:

1. Copy a file, testVerifyLog.xlsm
2. Paste into a subfolder of the same mapped network drive named:
   Copies of Logs
3. Rename the file with the current date (YYYYMMDD) added to the
   end, so that the final result for June 1, 2020 is:
   testVerifyLog_20200601.xlsm

The code below is what I have come up with but obviously does not work. The error I get in the PowerShell ISE is:

> copy-item : Illegal characters in path.
>
> At \TheMappedDrive\Share\AllDepts\OneDept\VerifyLogsMove.ps:2 char:1
>
> copy-item testVerifyLog.xlsm -
>   destination'\TheMappedDrive\Share\AllDepts\OneDept...
>
> CategoryInfo  : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], ArgumentException
>
> FullyQualifiedErrorID :
>   System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

```
Set-Location \\TheMappedDrive\Share\AllDepts
copy-item testVerifyLog.xlsm -destination '\\TheMappedDrive\Share\AllDepts\OneDept\Copies of Logs\testVerifyLog ; testVerifyLog-$(((get-date).ToUniversalTime()).ToString("yyyyMMdd")).xlsm'
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
$curDate = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd
$destinationFolder = '\\TheMappedDrive\Share\AllDepts\OneDept\Copies of Logs\testVerifyLog'
$destinationFile = Join-Path $destinationFolder -ChildPath ('testVerifyLog_' + $curDate + '.xlsm') 
copy-item '\\TheMappedDrive\Share\AllDepts\testVerifyLog.xlsm' -destination $destinationFile
```